# form does not submit when using ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a simple form which need to `submit` when click button and hide stuff with `ng-click`, it does submit the form when I don't add the ng-click for the hide stuff purpose, when I add the ng-click the form don't submit:

the form head :

```
 <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="edit(form)" novalidate ng-show="editorEnabledView">
```

the button :

```
<button analytics-on analytics-event="Bouton Terminer" analytics-category="Profil" ng-click="disableEdditing()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">{{ step == 2 ? 'Terminer' : 'Enregistrer' }}</button>
```

CTRL

```
$scope.editorEnabledView = false;

                $scope.showEdditing = function () {
                    $scope.editorEnabledView = true;
                    console.log("YES TRUE");
                }

                $scope.disableEdditing = function () {
                    $scope.editorEnabledView = false;
                }
```

my edit function :

```
$scope.edit = function (form) {
        if (!form.$valid) return;

        $scope.errors = {};
        if (!$scope.address.input) $scope.errors.address = 'Votre adresse de travail est obligatoire.';

        var data = {
            gender: $scope.user.gender,
            name: {
                first: $scope.user.name.first,
                last: $scope.user.name.last
            },
            phone: $scope.user.phone,
            job: {
                name: $scope.user.job.name,
                status: $scope.user.job.status
            },
            about: $scope.user.about,
            interests: $scope.user.interests
        };

        getAddress(function (response) {
            data.address = {
                full: response.formatted_address,
                city: getCity(response.address_components),
                latitude: response.geometry.location.lat(),
                longitude: response.geometry.location.lng(),
                timestamp: new Date()
            };

            User.update(data, function (user) {
                submit = true;
                Auth.update(user);
                if ($scope.step == 1) return $scope.step++;
                $location.path($scope.step == 2 ? '/' : '/users/view/' + user._id);
            }, function (err) {
                Auth.update(originalUser);
                $scope.user = originalUser;

                angular.forEach(err.data.errors, function (error, field) {
                    $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
                });
            });
        });
        //$scope.editorEnabledView = false;
    };
```

I discovered that when go to another page and come back to the user profile I see that the form get submitted !! but I want to see it after the submit

Comment: You sure you didn't make a type, and meant `disbaleEditing` instead? Otherwise please paste some more code, especially the angular logic.

Comment: no the ng-click does work and hide the contentent , but the form don't get submitted

Comment: and when I remove the ng-click the form get submitted ...

Comment: This code seems incomplete; could you post a snippet that has both and then mark the relevant form/button code lines? Currently I can't find a connection between `form` and `button`.

Comment: Can you show full code? Which means controller function also

Comment: Call the submit function before hide the form

Comment: I want it to submit and hid in the same time with the same button

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my answer cause now its clear that all you want to do is to hide your form after submit. This can be done with the use of `form.$submitted` and `ng-hide`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="edit(form)" ng-hide="form.$submitted" ng-show="!form.$submitted" novalidate >
</div>

<button analytics-on analytics-event="Bouton Terminer" analytics-category="Profil"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">{{ step == 2 ? 'Terminer' : 'Enregistrer' }}</button>
```

Comment: if you already have the submit function then hide the things you want from inside this function, why do u need the `ng-click` any way

Comment: `ng-click` will override the `ng-submit` thats why your form is not getting submitted...

Comment: This is not rigth. The ng-click does not override ng-submit. You can see it in my snippet.

Comment: @vinagreti you can read here on the angular documentation that only ng-click or ng-submit must be used, you cannot have both. please read : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: @Mouheb alright mate you told me that it worked, you can hide the form with this way `ng-hide="form.$submitted"`. No need for click event or anything

Comment: @Akis_Tfs, the doc says: "Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the ngClick and ngSubmit handlers together. See the form directive documentation for a detailed discussion of when ngSubmit may be triggered". Or, you can use both but for different functions or you will end up calling the same function twice. Again, you are wrong about your sentence. You can for sure use both. I did this in my snippet. You can see it below.

Comment: @vinagreti ok mate i have to suggest another way in a min

Comment: the profile don't get updated when the user click on submit instantly I need to refresh the page to see the profile updates ...

Comment: it's not a refresh actually, even when I go to another page and come back to the profile I find the Info was updated

Answer (score 0):

I did a snippet and everything seems to be working... I think you are doing something wrong. Maybe you are missing the ng-submit in the form tag. See my snippet and change your code.

```js
var $scope = {};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ngSubmitCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  
  $scope.editorEnabledView = true;
  
  $scope.showEdditing = function () {
      $scope.editorEnabledView = true;
      alert("showEdditing");
  }
  
  $scope.disableEdditing = function () {
      $scope.editorEnabledView = false;
    alert("disableEdditing");
  }
  
  $scope.edit = function (form) {
    alert("submitForm");
  }
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ngSubmitCtrl">
  <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="edit(form)" novalidate ng-show="editorEnabledView">
    <button 
            analytics-on analytics-event="Bouton Terminer" 
            analytics-category="Profil" 
            ng-click="disableEdditing()" 
            class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
            type="submit">{{ step == 2 ? 'Terminer' : 'Enregistrer' }}
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you send `form` inside `edit` call?

```
<form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="edit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="formData.name">
</form>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.edit = function() {
   console.log($scope.formData)
}
```

Or if you want to call edit function with parameter means

```
<form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="edit(form)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.name">
</form>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.edit = function(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

This should work. But we don't get your problem. If you show full code, we will help.